# In FlatPak, is it possible to always install packages under system instead of user?

Tags: software-installation, flatpak

On Debian/Ubuntu based Linux, the most common 3 package managers are apt, flatpak & snap.

Both apt & snap install packages for all users by default, flatpak is the only exception.

This has caused some wasted space as one application has to be installed in multiple location.

What's the simplest way to override this behaviour?

Comment: The docs at https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/using-flatpak.html state that "Flatpak commands are run system-wide by default". Which version are you using?

Comment: 1.14.4, shipped with Pop_OS 22.04

Comment: Seems like your system also should use this. Maybe Pop!_OS makes some changes? I `flatpak` command an alias? Or something is configured in `bashrc`?

Comment: hmm ... let me file a feature request. there is really no point in diverging from Ubuntu's convention